# How to create a function and call it on a function

Tags: jquery, function

I have the script bellow, and I need to create a function that changes my image then use it with *setInterval* to change the image every 2 seconds.

The counter (contar) works but it does not change the image.

what am i doing wrong?

```
var contar = 0; //counter value
var pausa = false;

function passar(){ //function that changes the image
    $("#"+contar).click(function(){ 
        $(".img").attr('src', 'imagens/'+contar+'.jpg'); //the image is from 1.jpg to 4.jpg
        $("#"+contar).addClass('active');
        console.log(contar);
    });
}

setInterval(function(){ //setinterval to use the function "passar" to change image
    contar++;
        if(contar<=4) { //my limit of images on the html
            passar(contar);
            console.log(contar);
        }else{
            contar = 0;
        };
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Please include your HTML. We don't know what `.img` might (or might not refer to). Also, any errors in the [JavaScript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)?

Comment: passar() should take an argument contar -- `function passar(contar) {` EDIT: nm, just saw you had global variable

Comment: @dave Or don't pass it in; as it is, it's ignored and the outer-scope `contar` is used everywhere. Nope OP says the counter is working, it's the image change that isn't happening.

Comment: Your comment at the end of the line `$(".img").attr('src', 'imagens/'+contar+'.jpg');` needs another slash: `//the image is from 1.jpg to 4.jpg`

Comment: Why do you have the `.click()` call? are you trying to only make the counter go when you click the image?

Comment: You don't need to pass contar in passar() if you are using it as a global var. But then, you are attaching a *click* event on passar() to an element named #{some_number}. That's doing nothing you are looking for, thus the images are not changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this. Remove the click event, looks unnecessary.

```
var contar = 0; //counter value
var max_images = 4; // my limit of images on the html
var pausa = false;

function passar(){ //function that changes the image    
    $(".img").attr('src', 'imagens/' + contar + '.jpg'); // the image is from 1.jpg to 4.jpg
    $("#"+contar).addClass('active');
    console.log(contar);
 }


setInterval(function(){ // setinterval to use the function "passar" to change image
contar++;
    if(contar<=max_images) { 
        passar(contar);
        console.log(contar);
    }else{
        contar = 0;
    };
}, 2000);
```

This is assuming your image elements have an .img class definition.

Comment: Yes i have an .img class.
The changes work very well, its working just fine without the click event.